# SonarQube web server with IP dynamic

Tags: ip, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-5.4

How I can configure the `sonar.web.host` with a dynamic IP? Would I need to change the properties file every time the IP changes?

```
# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: Why not leaving it uncommented ? In this case it'll just listen on all NICs, irrespective of the IP.

Comment: you're right. Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave `sonar.web.host` commented-out and SonarQube will listen on all NICs, irrespective of their IP address.